# IronRuby and XAML Databinding

Tags: .net, xaml, ironruby

Does anyone know if Microsoft plans on implementing XAML (declarative) databinding of IronRuby objects for Silverlight and WPF? Without it, using IronRuby for Silverlight/WPF development really isn't all that compelling (IMO).

Answer (score 0):

you can use databinding in WPF. That just works

And in Silverlight 4 you should be able to use databinding with DLR objects as well.
If you're using Silverlight < v4 then you can still use a workaround by creating an observable dictionary in C# and storing your view data stuff in that dictionary instead of a pure ruby object.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at my earlier answer [Building IronRuby WPF GUIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320180/building-ironruby-wpf-guis/8361671#8361671) regarding GUI programming with Ironruby and XAML.
Ironruby Unleashed explains this in more detail.